# ¿Por qué el navegador no vuelve a abrir?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

El código es el siguiente:

```
proxy = open(file="proxylist.txt", mode="r")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
time.sleep(1)

def main():

    try:
    
        proxy1 = proxy.readline().rstrip()
        print(proxy1)
        consulta = driver.get('http://'+proxy1+'/www.fotocasa.es/es/')
        aceptarcookies = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/footer/div/button[2]')

    except Exception as ex:
        driver.quit()
        print(ex)
        main()

    finally:
        pass
```

Cuando el primer porxy no realiza la consulta, pasa al siguiente pero, el navegador se cierra y no vuelve a abrir intentando hacer esto con el siguiente. ¿Por qué?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tómate un momento y analiza el código.

Cuando obtienes una excepción al ejecutar el código dentro del `try` haces lo siguiente:

```
driver.quit()
print(ex)
main()
```

La llamada a [`driver.quit()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.quit) cierra el navegador abierto y finaliza la ejecución del driver.

Posteriormente llamas a la función `main` nuevamente con un driver que solo iniciaste una vez fuera de la función y que ya no se encuentra disponible porque decidiste llamar a `driver.quit()`.

La solución consiste en mover la llamada al final del programa, fuera de la función `main`, para que el driver pueda terminar su trabajo y liberar los recursos en uso. De lo contrario, quedarían los procesos abiertos y deberías finalizarlos manualmente desde el administrador de tareas.

```
proxy = open(file="proxylist.txt",  mode="r")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable- extensions')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
time.sleep(1)

def main():
    try:  
        proxy1 = proxy.readline().rstrip()
        print(proxy1)
        consulta = driver.get('http://'+proxy1+'/www.fotocasa.es/es/')
        aceptarcookies = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/footer/div/button[2]')

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        main()

driver.quit()
```